# Нейронная сеть не обучается глубже 1 слоя

Tags: javascript, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Нейросеть прекрасно справляется с линейными примерами, но когда добавляю хотя бы один скрытый слой - ошибка незначительно снижается и остается на одном и том же уровне бесконечно.

Пробовал и подбирал самые разные примеры, разное количество слоев и нейронов, но ничего не меняется. Даже y = x1 && x2 не считает (пробовал 0-3 скрытых слоя с разным количеством нейронов).

Использую логистическую функцию для начала.

```
        function get_test_data(){
            var p = [MyRand(-2, 2), MyRand(-2, 2)];
            return{
                p: p,
                res: [p[0] && p[1] ? 1 : 0]
            }
        }
        function activate_fn1(x, de){
            if(!de){
                return 1/(1 + Math.exp(-x));
            }
            else{
                return activate_fn1(x, false)*(1 - activate_fn1(x, false));
            }
        }
        async function learn(){
            var ggg = 0;
            while(1){
                await sleep(sleeping);
                errors[ggg] = []; // для истории ошибок
                var test_data = get_test_data();
                for (var i = 0; i < test_data.p.length; i++) {
                    layers[0][layers[0].length - i - 1].value = test_data.p[i]; // заполняю х1, х2...
                }

                // прогоняю данные по нейросети
                for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < connections[i].length; k++) {
                        if(layers[i + 1][k].is_bias) continue; // пропускаю нейрон смещения
                        layers[i + 1][k].value = 0;
                        for (var j = 0; j < connections[i][k].length; j++) {
                            layers[i + 1][k].value += layers[i][j].value*connections[i][k][j]; // значение += входное * вес связи
                        }
                        layers[i + 1][k].value = activate_fn1(layers[i + 1][k].value, false); // пропускаю значение через ф-ю активации;
                    }
                }
                //вычисляю ошибку
                for (var i = 0; i < test_data.res.length; i++) {
                    var diff = activate_fn1(test_data.res[i], false) - layers[layers.length - 1][i].value; // ожидаемый сигнал - полученный
                    layers[layers.length - 1][i].error = diff;
                    errors[ggg].push(Math.abs(diff));
                }
                // вычисляю ошибки для скрытых нейронов
                for (var i = connections.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < connections[i][0].length; k++) {
                        layers[i][k].error = 0;
                        for (var j = 0; j < connections[i].length; j++) {
                            if(layers[i][k].is_bias) continue; // пропускаю нейрон смещения
                            layers[i][k].error += layers[i + 1][j].error*connections[i][j][k]; // ошибка += ошбика след. нейрона * вес связи
                        }
                        layers[i][k].error *= activate_fn1(layers[i][k].error, true); // ошибка = f'(x)
                    }
                }
                //исправляю ошибки
                for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < connections[i].length; j++) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < connections[i][j].length; k++) {
                            // вес += скорость * ошибку выходного нейрона * значение входного нейрона
                            connections[i][j][k] = connections[i][j][k] + speed*layers[i + 1][j].error*layers[i][k].value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ggg++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Можете скинуть пожалуйста весь код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести его у себя.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков https://shumik.site/archive/neural/ тут в основном файле есть код, а в воркере именно обучение, сори за плохой код)

Comment: Не нашел :) Может не там искал. Редко когда код скидывают сайтом. Я просто `Ctrl + S` нажал и скачал `html` файл, но в нем например есть функция `activation_fn1` но она закоменчена и не та, что в вопросе у вас. И кстати я думаю роли не играет, но входные значения всегда = 0, так же значения на нейронах смещения = 0, а если входные = 0 и нет нейронов смещения, то почему то в скрытых нейронах появляются значения не = 0. И там еще пару ошибок. Решил написать, а то вдруг с нейронкой связаны ошибки. Вряд ли конечно.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков https://shumik.site/archive/neural/learn.js это воркер, он не в самом файле)

Comment: Честно меня смутила формула нахождения ошибок выходных нейронов. У вас это производная идеального ответа - выходное значение нейрона. Такую впервые просто вижу. Попробуйте использовать такую формулу: `error[i] = (ideal - output) * deriv(output)` У вас это так: `var diff = activate_fn1(layers[layers.length - 1][i].value) * (test_data.res[i] - layers[layers.length - 1][i].value);`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков производная output или diff? Так как Вы написали не работает совсем

Comment: Первая формула это общая. Второе я в вашем случае написал формулу. Там где у вас `diff` высчитывается. `//вычисляю ошибку`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков не хочет никак работать:/ Ошибка остается на том же уровне в любой задаче с любым кол-вом нейронов

Comment: В общем пытался куски кода соединить в один работающий (лучше конечно весь код нейронки в 1 класс вынести). Потом попытался разобраться в вашем коде. Как я понял у вас у `connections` структура такая: `connections[индекс слоя][правый слой][левый слой]` мое мнение, что это же максимально не удобно. Так же я не нашел, где вы находите результирующую ошибку. Обычно это просто среднее арифметическое ошибок выходного слоя. (Как я понял он где-то в файле с выводом в виде графика, что максимально не удобно)

Comment: Так же я заметил, что у вас нет нормализации данных. Можете почитать про это [тут](https://www.mql5.com/ru/articles/497#:~:text=Нормализация%20входных%20данных%20-%20это%20процесс,что%20приведет%20к%20неверным%20решениям.) Так же не забывайте денормализовать данные. В общем дальше уже сложно стало :) Рекомендую потратить немного времени и переписать нейронку по новой. Больше углубившись в ооп.

Comment: Для биасов нужно ошибку вычислять и обновлять, изучите код моего проекта для полносвязной сети(на Python) https://github.com/kosta2222/brainy/blob/master/brainy/net_con_.py

Comment: @Константин зачем для биаса ошибка если в него не входят связи?

Comment: У них связи есть, только сигнал постоянный +1 или -1.

Comment: Так же я заметил, что вы не используете гиперпараметр - момент. Вот [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/313216/) где на картинках показано, что без момента, ошибка может просто застыть на одном из экстремуме, а для обучения нужно ошибку свести к минимуму (надеюсь математически все верно сказал :))

Comment: @Константин связи исходящие, но для них ошибка "левого" нейрона не учитывается

Comment: Поэтому у вас может и не работать, я тоже ошибку биасов не прорабатывал и у меня сеть не совсем справлялась.Когда сделал ошибку для биасов-горазда лучше.

Comment: @Константин а для просчета каких весов она используется?

Comment: Для связей именно на биасах.Я давал этим связям ошибку слоя.И отнимал при обновлениях, только сигнал был +1.